# Curva ROC para GLMM é possivel?

Tags: r, regressão

Amigos, 
A minha duvida é a seguinte, eu estou utilizando os seguinte codigo em R para construção de uma curva ROC , mas não sei dizer se em caso de GLMM (Modelo Linear Generalizado MIsto) eu posso utilizar e se ele neste caso o codigo então irá  considerar a parte aleatoria tambem ou somente os fixos tais como ocorre na Regressão Logística, o que não me daria uma informação correta.

```
 library(ROCR)
 pred <- prediction(fitted(gg1), dados$status)
 perf <- performance(pred, measure = "tpr", x.measure = "fpr")
 plot(perf, main = "ROC", col = "blue", lwd = 3)
 abline(a = 0, b = 1, lwd = 2, lty = 2)
 perf.auc <- performance(pred, measure = "auc")
 (area <- performance(pred, "auc"))
```

Comment: A curva ROC simplesmente categoriza uma variável contínua em uma categórica de 2 categorias apartir de outra variável categórica (https://gpestatistica.netlify.com/blog/curvaroc/). Se o `fitted(gg1)` considera o efeito aleatório, então a curva "também irá". Só que vai depender a forma que você especifica o modelo misto. O seu dado é do tipo antes e depois? Utilizar uma curva ROC para o Antes, e outra para o Depois não seria mais interessante? (pois os pontos de cortes devem ser bem diferentes para esses 2 momentos).